# Threads and Shared Pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Do the new smart pointers work with threads correctly?

Ex a thread creates a copy of the pointer while another thread is in the process messing up the reference count?

Comment: Because you mention reference counting I assume you're talking about [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)?  Then the answer is yes: "All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object." (From the linked reference)

Comment: The reference counter is atomic, so this is fine.

Comment: shared_ptr is a bit of a halfway solution with regards to thread safety, however it's reference counting (block) is threadsafe.

Comment: The pointer being is threadsafe does not make the pointed to object threadsafe ofc.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Cited reference seems not to imply accessing the *same* SP from different threads is safe, though – just for completeness; setting up an environment in a way this might occur appears questionable (at least) anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` consists of 3 parts,

1. control block containing the reference count is an atomic, two threads each one having their copy of `shared_ptr` to the same object can copy or delete their pointers without race conditions.
2. the object pointed to by the `shared_ptr`, it is not protected from concurrent access, if you have a `shared_ptr<vector<int>>` you shouldn't be using `push_back` on the vector from two threads concurrently.
3. the `std::shared_ptr` object itself is not threadsafe, if one thread tries to copy a `shared_ptr` while another thread is trying to modify it to point elsewhere then you get a potential use after free. if two threads have access to the same `shared_ptr` (for example a global `shared_ptr`) then you have to use [atomic<shared_ptr>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) instead.